# Proof involving Linear Isometry

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, isometry

[image]

Hi,

For this problem my approach is obviously lacking, as a I do not utilize the hint. But I am not sure how to utilize the hint or why it is necessary to do this problem.

This is what I did:

$$ \langle Ax, Ay \rangle = \langle x,y\rangle $$

$$ A\langle x,y\rangle = \langle x,y\rangle $$

$$ \|A\langle x,y\rangle\| = \| \langle x,y\rangle \|$$

The above only holds if $\|A\| = 1$, which is true with $A$ is an orthogonal transformation.

Thus,

$$ \|Ax \| = \|x\| $$

Comment: There is a problem in the second line because $\langle .,.\rangle:\mathbb{R}^n\times \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ and  $A:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ so you cannot compose them

Comment: In addition to the serious gap Soma mentions, you're only addressing the direction "orthogonal implies linear isometry". The hint is all but essential for the converse direction, "linear isometry implies orthogonal.

Comment: Okay, I see what you are saying. If I applied the hint and got:

|| Ax + Ay ||^2 - || Ax - Ay ||^2 = || x + y ||^2 - || x - y ||^2 

Could you give a hint on the next step? @AndrewD.Hwang

Answer (score 0):

The proof is split in two parts, one for each direction. The first one is easy.

Show: $(Ax,Ay)=(x,y) \Rightarrow ||Ax||=||x||$:
$$
||Ax||^2=(Ax,Ax)=(x,x)=||x||^2
$$
The second part,
the $\Leftarrow$ direction:
$$
||x+y||^2=||A(x+y)||^2=\langle A(x+y),A(x+y)\rangle=||Ax||^2+||Ay||^2+2\langle Ax,Ay\rangle
$$
and
$$
||x-y||^2=||A(x-y)||^2=\langle A(x-y),A(x-y)\rangle=||Ax||^2+||Ay||^2-2\langle Ax,Ay\rangle
$$
subtracting:
$$
||x+y||^2-||x-y||^2=4\langle Ax,Ay\rangle
$$
Finally, using the given identitiy:
$$
\langle Ax,Ay\rangle=\frac{1}{4}(||x+y||^2-||x-y||^2)=\langle x,y\rangle
$$

Remark: The basic idea is to express the scalar product $\langle Ax,Ay\rangle$ in terms of $||x+y||^2$ norms (plus and minus) and then using the given identity.